# controlling options in an activity using a switch and displaying summary whether on/off

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I want to add an option to my preference activity similar to what is seen in chrome "home page"," save passwords " options (android app). This from my understanding launches an activity that holds a switch which controls sub options. This furthermore gives a summary indicating whether on/off. My question is how do I go about implementing some similar with regards to preference activity as I can't find examples to achieve this.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Preference:

> A Preference object is the building block for a single setting. Each Preference appears as an item in a list and provides the appropriate UI for users to modify the setting. For example, a CheckBoxPreference creates a list item that shows a checkbox, and a ListPreference creates an item that opens a dialog with a list of choices.
>
> Each Preference you add has a corresponding key-value pair that the system uses to save the setting in a default SharedPreferences file for your app's settings. When the user changes a setting, the system updates the corresponding value in the SharedPreferences file for you. The only time you should directly interact with the associated SharedPreferences file is when you need to read the value in order to determine your app's behavior based on the user's setting.
>
> The value saved in SharedPreferences for each setting can be one of the following data types:
>
> - Boolean
> - Float
> - Int
> - Long
> - String
> - String Set
>
> Because your app's settings UI is built using Preference objects instead of View objects, you need to use a specialized Activity or Fragment subclass to display the list settings:
>
> - If your app supports versions of Android older than 3.0 (API level 10 and lower), you must build the activity as an extension of the PreferenceActivity class.
> - On Android 3.0 and later, you should instead use a traditional Activity that hosts a PreferenceFragment that displays your app settings. However, you can also use PreferenceActivity to create a two-pane layout for large screens when you have multiple groups of settings.

An example of the XML with sub-views like you want:

```
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- opens a subscreen of settings -->
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
    android:title="@string/voicemail"
    android:persistent="false">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="button_voicemail_provider_key"
        android:title="@string/voicemail_provider" ... />
    <!-- opens another nested subscreen -->
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="button_voicemail_setting_key"
        android:title="@string/voicemail_settings"
        android:persistent="false">
        ...
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="button_voicemail_ringtone_key"
        android:title="@string/voicemail_ringtone_title"
        android:ringtoneType="notification" ... />
    ...
</PreferenceScreen>
...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

You can find all about it in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `PreferenceActivity` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) has a pretty good example of usage. 
Is there something more that you are looking for?

Comment: I mean that there is an option in chrome.apk like the "homepage" option that launches an another activity which has a switch that controls sub options in the same activity. My issue is how do I implement such.